# Creating a file in an App Engine project

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to create a .json file for each user with a user ID. For example, 123456.json in 'data' folder. When I try this without a Flask server using a simple test file, it works:

```
with open('data/3456789.json', "w+") as f:
    print("test")
```

However, when I call it in a Flask server created in App Engine I'm getting error `No such file or directory: 'data/3456789.json'`

This is how my `main.py` looks:

```
import os, sys
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET'])
def createFile():
  with open('data/3456789.json', "w+") as f:
    print("test")
return "Welcome"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))
  print("Starting app on port %d" % port)
  app.run(debug=False, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

`main.py` works fine on my own PC without any errors. Any ideas?

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Don't rollback valid edits on your post. Stack Overflow is a community curated site, where users edit others posts and make them better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App engine doesn't let your deployed app write to the file system.  That is part of the app engine sandbox.

You can, however, read from the file system. If you can create the json files on your personal computer, you can then deploy them with your app and your app will be able to read these files.